# Nested Annotation in JCodeModel

Tags: jcodemodel

I would like to create a CompoundIndexes annotation from the XML file like below.

[image: enter image description e]

However, I don't know how to put CompoundIndex Annotation with a parameter inside the CompoundIndexes Annotation. Here's what I've tried.

```
JAnnotationUse indexesAnnotation = currentClass.annotate(CompoundIndexes.class);

JAnnotationArrayMember arrayMember = indexesAnnotation.paramArray("value");

 JAnnotationUse indexesParameter = currentClass.annotate(CompoundIndex.class)
.param("def", some_parameter);

arrayMember.param(indexesParameter);
```

However, I end up getting the below result.

[image]

How can I only get the nested compoundIndexes part and get rid of the two componenet index annotations below?

In the otherword, how can a create an annotation and pass it into another annotation as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, it seems that `param()` is depreciated and suggests to use `annotate()` instead.  Using `annotate()` sovles your problem:

```
JAnnotationUse indexesAnnotation = currentClass.annotate(CompoundIndexes.class);

JAnnotationArrayMember arrayMember = indexesAnnotation.paramArray("value");

arrayMember.annotate(CompoundIndex.class)
        .param("name", "email_age")
        .param("def", "{'email.id' : 1, 'age' : 1}");
```

Gives:

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "email_age", def = "{'email.id' : 1, 'age' : 1}")
})
```